# image uploaded to wall using hackbook-url generated

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have uploaded an image using hackbook for android to my wall. the url of the image is this.

```
http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=107428579392184&set=a.100386686763040.301.100003751260617&type=3&l=74e355fdc3&theater
```

Ok so here are my questions:
This `fbid=107428579392184` and this `100003751260617` are the ids i get as a response when image is uploaded. what about the rest numbers? What are they?

I want to be able to "guess" the url generated for that photo, knowing only the ids given back from my app? Is is possible?